# Are there any special properties in regards to concavity for a point where second derivative of a function = 0, but does not change sign?

Tags: derivatives

Assuming we have a function

$$
F(x)=\frac{x^4}{12}
$$
with second derivatie:
$$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(\frac{x^4}{12}\right)=x^2
$$
At x=0 second derivative is 0, but since the sign does not change, we don't have an inflection point. Second derivative of 0 at x means, that at the function is neither concave up, nor concave down at x. Therefore, the function is concave up everywhere, except at x=0.

Concave up means that a line segment between any two points on the graph of the function lies above or on the graph. Since the function is not concave up at x=0, above segment property does not hold everywhere for such a function?

Comment: `the function is neither concave up, nor concave down at x` Convexity is not and cannot be defined at a single isolated point. The function is in fact strictly convex on $\,\mathbb{R}\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that since $f''(x)\ge 0$ and $f''(x)=0$ in a single point (not on an interval) then $f(x)=\frac{x^4}{12}$ is strictly convex.

Comment: So, nothing special at all about this point?

Comment: @IvanKoshelev the condition $f''(x)\ge 0$ suffices to establish that $f$ is convex and since $f''(x)=0 \iff x=0$ we have that $f(x)$ is strictly convex . Thus nothing special about this point, in the sense that $f(x)$ is strictly convex as $x^2$ and more in general $x^{2n}$.